# removing directory in apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP site which replaces an ASP site, so the path structure is different.

In the URLs, I need to match http://apache.site/Cartv3/Details.asp & redirect to another location. What is the correct syntax to match that URL fragment?

I've already tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} CartV3/results1.asp?Category=60
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home-study/A-Levels/1/page-1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^CartV3/Details\.asp?ProductID=1004 home-study/A-Levels/1/page-1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meed to read more about mod_rewrite. Remember RewriteRule doesn't match query string. You attempt needs to be rewritten as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category=60$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^CartV3/results1\.asp$ /home-study/A-Levels/1/page-1? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

PS: `?` after `page-1` is a special mod_rewrite syntax to strip original query string. If you want to keep original query string in rewritten URL then take out `?` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to match the query string, which has to be done by a separate `RewriteCond`.  If you want the match specifically "Category=60", then you can add it as a Condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Category=60
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /CartV3/results1.asp
RewriteRule .* home-study/A-Levels/1/page-1?
```

This will match `http://example.com/CartV3/results1.asp?Category=60` and redirect.  The `?` at the end of the rule stops "?Category=60" being to the resulting URI.

If you don't care about the value in the query string, then you can remove the first condition.